# fadeOut images which are not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a gallery of images. What I am trying to achieve is pretty simple - whatever image the user clicks on will stay on the page whilst the rest will fade out. I am trying to achieve this by adding a class to the clicked image, and then targetting the non-clicked through the fact that it does not have the class. However, I seem to be getting no response as nothing really happens when I click on the image.

HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center famImages">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="images/5.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="images/6.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

</div>
```

JS/JQUERY:

```
$("img").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("class","active"){
   if(!$("img").hasClass("active")){
   !$("img").hasClass("active").fadeOut("slow");
}

}

})
```

Comment: There is a parse error in the javascript shown. Please make sure it is not a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.not()` to exclude elements from a selection. Note, given the requirement it is not clear how the element which have faded out would regain visibility

```
$(".img-responsive").on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".img-responsive").not(this).removeClass("active").fadeOut("slow")
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help, guest271314

Answer (score 1):

First add a class `active` to the clicked image then read all the images and foreach image check if it doesn't contain(`hasClass()`) the class `active` to `fadeOut()` it:

```js
$("img").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("img").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){$(this).fadeOut("slow");}
  })
});
```

```css
img{
width:32px;
height:32px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center famImages">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/color/Gaming//pokecoin1600.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/color/Messaging//tongue_out1600.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gN6iBKP1b2GTXZZoCxhyXiYIAh8QJ_8xzlhEK6csyDadA4GdkEdIEy9Bc8s5jozt1g=w300" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

First, add the class using the appropriate jquery function. Then, I suggest using the [not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector from jquery. Jquery executes its functions on array-like elements. Using this code, it will fade-out all elements that are `img` without the `active` class

```
$("img").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("img:not(.active)").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Or, if the active class is not needed, then a simple solution would be

```
$("img").click(function(){
  $("img").not(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add or remove any class. You simply fade out all images that are not the clicked images:

```js
$("img").click(function() {
  $("img").not(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center famImages">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="images/4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="images/5.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="images/6.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the quickest, easiest solution. Than you very much for your input sir!